# Is there an issue with this .htaccess which would really slow down a page request?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Since adding this basic .htaccess to my index directory, each page load slows down by maybe 20-30 seconds:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)-(.+) movie.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Is there some malformation or bad regex formatting here? I can't see anything wrong with it.

Thanks!

As an update, just these 2 lines are enough to put the slow down on:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
```

Comment: Using `^(.+)-(.+)` is not the optimal choice … but is it really 20–30 seconds?

Comment: Yes, deleting the .htaccess makes the page loads instant.

Comment: what about the [NCL]? this could save some time too

Answer (score 0):

Even though I think that 20-30 seconds is a little bit far-fetched, here some concerns about your current regex:

- Part of your regex isn't required, so drop it. Especially if this part already looks like a lot of backtracking (and `(.+)` does). Thus you may reduce the regex to `^(.+)-`.
- You are matching an ID with `(.+)`. That isn't the optimal approach. Better use `([^-]+)` instead. This will mach any char that isn't an `-` (and that's what you want.)

The resulting Rule thus is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)- movie.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Even better (this allows only integral IDs):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)- movie.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to have sped it up though. Is it possible it's a server config problem?

Comment: Probably. 20-30 seconds is way to slow, even for your regex ;)

Comment: Right, I'll have to investigate further then. Thanks for the regex tips, I'll bear them in mind and change my current ones.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running requests through your movie script. So how long does it take your movie.php script to run? If it takes 20-30 seconds, well, then there you go!

Comment: The rule just redirects pages which meet that criteria to movie.php, which loads instantly anyway, so I can't see that as the problem really?

Comment: It would be a problem if movie.php ran for 30 seconds. Since it doesn't, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on rewrite logging and crank the level up, see what your RewriteRule is doing:

```
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel
```

If the regex is having to work overtime, you'll quickly see Apache's error log explode in size, especially at the higher levels of rewrite logging.